# React-hook-form Have to press twice for deleting the last character of input and twice for enter the first character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I use React Hook Form to validate my form including many input. Everything is five except one problem that I have to press backspace twice for deleting the last character and twice for enter the first character. For example. If i need to show value of input is 'jonh', then I have to press 'j' twice so that this letter can be shown. And when I delete 'john', a press 1 backspace for 'n', 1 backspace for 'h', 1 backspace for 'o' BUT 2 backspace for 'j'. I thought this is from react hook form because I don't use, it's no problem. Appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

Codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-j63o9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You are not using React-Hook-Form right now. You only imported it and registered it.

This is how to use React-Hook-Form:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'


const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      name: '',
      code: '',
      description: '',
      price: '',
      weight: '',
      long: '',
      width: '',
      high: '',
    },
  });

const onSubmit = async (data) => {

};

<form className="popup-product__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <input
        type="text"
        name="name"
        className="form-control"
        placeholder="Message"
        ref={register({
            required: 'Errors Message ....',
        })}
    />
    {errors.name && (
        <div className="form-error">
            {errors.name.message}
        </div>
    )}
   <input value="Submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry for missing code when copying. You can see it in Codesanbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-j63o9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: My answer above was complete. See this working [CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-forked-06kof?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Can you please review, 1) it doesnt show errors message if delete input value;   2) in my project I use onChange handler for input tag but you removed it .....

Comment: I tested it and it still displays error message when you delete your input. You don't need an onChange handler for React Hook Form. That was the reason you needed an extra key press. React Hook Form takes care of the onChange and setState of all of the fields on the form.